# In Python Plot, how do I plot the values of my chart as X.X Million, rather than the whole number ie. 1,000,000

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm plotting the passenger per year, but aggregated data is in millions, and I would like the graph to show just X.X Millions

This is the code:

```
Pax_Major=MajorCarriers.groupby(by=["YEAR"])["PASSENGERS"].sum().reset_index().sort_values(["YEAR"])
```

Then I set this to plot (the code I found from an online example)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13.33,7.5), dpi = 96)

bar1=ax.bar(Pax_Major["YEAR"], Pax_Major["PASSENGERS"], width=0.6)

ax.set_xlabel('', fontsize=12, labelpad=10)
ax.xaxis.set_label_position("bottom")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda s, i : f'{s:,.0f}')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=2, labelbottom=True, bottom=True, labelsize=12, labelrotation=0)
labels = ["97", "98", "99", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"]
ax.set_xticks(Pax_Major['YEAR'], labels)
 
ax.set_ylabel('Passengers per year', fontsize=12, labelpad=10)
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("left")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda s, i : f'{s:,.0f}')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=2, labeltop=False, labelbottom=True, bottom=False, labelsize=12)

ax.bar_label(bar1, labels=[f'{e:,.0f}' for e in Pax_Major['PASSENGERS']], padding=3, color='black', fontsize=8)

colours = ["#bbdefb","#2196f3"]
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("colour_map", colours, N=256)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(Pax_Major['PASSENGERS'].min(), Pax_Major['PASSENGERS'].max())
bar1 = ax.bar(Pax_Major['YEAR'], Pax_Major['PASSENGERS'], color=cmap(norm(Pax_Major['PASSENGERS'])), width=0.6, zorder=2)
```

This is what I get:

[image: Passenger Per years]

But Instead of, ie., 65,073,314,271 in 1997, I would like to have 65.1 Million shown in the graph.

--
Thank you!

Comment: Easy solution is probably divide all values by 1e6, and then adjust the y axis label to `"Millions of passengers per year"` or `"passengers per year (millions)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ax.bar_label(bar1, labels=[f'{e:,.0f}' for e in Pax_Major['PASSENGERS']], padding=3, color='black', fontsize=8)
```

This is the line that sets your labels. Change how you're generating the labels, like so:

```
new_labels = [
    f'{(e / 1000000):,.1f} million' 
    for e in Pax_Major['PASSENGERS']
]
ax.bar_label(bar1, labels=new_labels, padding=3, color='black', fontsize=8)
```

`f'{(e / 1000000):,.1f} million'` is a format-string. Everything inside the `{}` before the `:` will be evaluated and then the `:,.1f` specifies to use '1,000.00' rather than '1.000,00' format, and to round to 1 decimal place. That gets combined with the rest of the format string, which is just the word "million".